# Samsaran Witch : as an Hexer, Support / Control

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, optimization

***DISCLAIMER : This character is expected to take part in a coherent campaign, it is not a sandbox exercise. Characters will start at level 1.***

Hello everyone,
I am looking at fleshing a **good** Samsaran **Witch** for a long campaign likely to reach Mythic proportion (Wrath of the Righteous). We are going to encounter a lot of Demons, as such I expect good Will saves so I planned on beefing up my Hex and focus on buff then control. I don't look to be a power house just being able to hold my ground against demons on a regular basis is fine. Yet I would like to be able to up my game if needed.

My group lack support/heal (Diviner Mage, Ranged Rogue and Tank Palie) so I expect to take this role.I know it is not the best position for a Witch, I hope on using the Mystic past life to bring some good stuff to help.

So far I came up with the following:

---

**Familiar** : compsognathus 9 (+ 4 init please!)

**Patron** : Healing (nothing appealed to me much and it will allow me to get some much needed spell for my group (Restoration anyone?)

**Traits**: (2 + drawbacks are allowed)

> - ??? => Must come from the campaign player guide
> - ??? I thought about Adopted - Honeyed Tongue but it sounds really cheesy... so it is likely to be Reactionary

**Point buy**: 25

> - Str: 10
> - Dex: 12
> - Con: 14(12)
> - Int: 18(20)
> - Wis: 10(12)
> - Cha: 11

**Skills:** 2+5

> - *Fly (Dex) 0
> - *Intimidate (Cha)
> - *Knowledge (Arcana) (Int)  1
> - *Knowledge (History) (Int) 1
> - *Knowledge (Nature) (Int) 1
> - *Knowledge(Planes) (Int) 1
> - *Spellcraft (Int) 1
> - *Use Magic Device (Cha) 1
> - Perception 1
>
> I will max all the selected skill and when my int allow it, I will put
> 1 point in Heal then max fly.

**Feats**:

> - 1)Ability Focus : Hex - Slumber
> - 3)Extra Hexes
> - 5)Accursed Hex
> - 7)Leadership
> - 9)Craft Wondruous Item ?
> - 11)Split Hex
> - 13)???
> - 15)???
> - 17)???
> - 19)???

**Hexes**

> - Slumber
> - Misfortune
> - Extra Hexes- Cackle
> - Evil Eye
> - Fortune
> - Flight
> - Ice Tomb
> - Hag's eye
> - Retribution
> - Agony
> - Forced Reincarnation
> - ???

---

I have already a pretty good idea of what I am doing but there is still some grey area, mainly on the spells and metamagic as I will take the alternate: Mystic Past Life (Su).

To sum up, my questions are :

- What spells/Metamagic combination should I take to fulfill my role as an Hexer, support / control taking into account Mystic past life ?
- Bonus : Should I take Improved familiar and which familiar?
- Bonus : I am happy with my feats / traits but any advice is welcome.

---

Updated stat to reflect game restriction: No dump stat (nothing below 10), I will put a point into charisma sooner or later.

Comment: If your group is short on healing, did you consider the Healing hex?  Assuming no hirelings/cohorts/NPCs/mounts traveling with your party, it's basically giving you four 2nd level spell slots every day for Cure Moderate Wounds.  And of course Major Healing is several free Cure Critical Wounds per day.  Life Giver is Resurrection without the 10k cost.  If you have cohorts, hirelings, or anyone else that might ever need healing, the first two give even more heals per day at no extra charge.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the pointers.Oups, I forgot to say that we are starting from lvl 1. Considering the healing Hex is one pop a day on each player it is pretty okay at first but past a few level it will turn into not so usefull for the players but I see the drift and with the large combat with lot of npc it may come handy... I will consider it, thank you!

Regarding Life giver, if we don't end up with a hireling able to cast the spell Breath of life, I will more than likely take it as there is little interesting hexes at such a high level.

Comment: If you're using retraining rules, you can drop Healing once you can get Major Healing.  Major Healing pretty much never goes out of style.  At least four free 4th level spells per day dedicated to healing.  It's not enough for a full answer, but I'm glad my comments helped ^_^

Comment: Only because I am guilty of power gaming, if you go with base stats of 10/14/15/17/9/11, middle aged would give you 9/13/14/18/10/12 your dexterity would be 1 higher than your current. Alternatively: 11/13/15/18/7/11 would give you 10/12/14/19/8/12 (food for thought if you wanted higher int)

Comment: @DanceSC, cheers for the idea but taking into account the campaign setting and the group a short lived character aging my character more than he already is would be a real pain...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a "healing witch," the Healing hex is absolutely worth it. One free healing spell for anyone every day. You will use this all the time instead of wasting potions/money. You will use this hex forever.

Be very aware that Cackle requires a move action, and can very quickly degrade your action economy until you are caught in a move-and-cackle trap.

Don't worry about the Fly skill until 5th level.

Against anything mindless or immune to mind-affecting effects, your hexes are all but useless.

Prehensile Hair is extremely useful for touch spells or trip attacks.

The Spite spell + Vampiric Touch is a fantastic combination, doing a minimum of 3d6 points of damage to a successful attacker, and granting you that as temporary HP.

Do everything in your power to get a Witching Gown.

Comment: Thank you for those nice ideas, I will take them into consideration (updated first post). Now, I am left wondering how to rearrange all my hexes to take the healing one without turning myself into a healbot unable to do what a witch is good for (cursing BBEG to death!)